# How can I handle errors when copying file over Network

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm recycling code from an old database.

For one person, located half way across the country, I believe there may be some connection issue.

```
Public Function BackUpBackend()

    Dim Source As String
    Dim Target As String
    Dim retval As Integer

    Source = "\\network\backend\accessfile.accdb"

    Target = "\\network\backend\backup\"
    Target = Target & Format(Date, "mm-dd") & "@"
    Target = Target & Format(Time, "hh-mm") & ".accdb"

    retval = 0
    Dim objFSO As Object
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    retval = objFSO.CopyFile(Source, Target, True)
    Set objFSO = Nothing

End Function
```

Is there any way to detect connection errors in this code? And if there is, can the connection be re-established or just stop the backup process all together when the issue comes up?

Comment: if the remote workstation has a shared drive then copy a large file to the shared drive, then read it back. check speed of the file transfer and check if there is any corruption after the round-trip  ... then run the code on your workstation with the accessfile.accdb on the remote workstation ... something may show up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VBA you can do

```
On Error Resume Next
```

which will continue past errors. This can be dangerous though, so it's often best to switch on error handling again as soon as possible with

```
On Error Goto 0
```

You can define custom handlers for errors that crop up that you want to take specific action on:
From the [VBA Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266173(v=vs.60).aspx):

```
Sub InitializeMatrix(Var1, Var2, Var3, Var4)
   On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
   . . .
   Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
   . . .
   Resume Next
End Sub
```

So you might do something like: (I've not tested)

```
Public Function BackUpBackend()

    Dim Source As String
    Dim Target As String
    Dim retval As Integer


    Source = "\\network\backend\accessfile.accdb"

    Target = "\\network\backend\backup\"
    Target = Target & Format(Date, "mm-dd") & "@"
    Target = Target & Format(Time, "hh-mm") & ".accdb"

    retval = 0
    Dim objFSO As Object
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    On Error Goto ErrorHandler
    retval = objFSO.CopyFile(Source, Target, True)
    Set objFSO = Nothing
    On Error Goto 0

    Exit Function

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox("Backup failed. If this happens often contact IT", vbExclamation )

End Function
```

Comment: This is great, I will verify that this works on Monday when she gets back as I don't have any way to replicate it right now. Appreciate your help! I'm still trying to grasp the "Error Handling" at the moment

Comment: You're welcome. Do some general reading around error and exception handling which might help. Also you can deliberately make it fail by putting in a bad target path to check your code

Comment: I suppose I could do that, but that would be different from a connection loss wouldn't it?

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the feedback